# Windows-like logo in Halt and Catch Fire intro

Tags: title-sequence, halt-and-catch-fire

In AMC's Halt and Catch Fire TV series, its intro at some point shows a Windows-like logo image. What is the image alluded for? Since it was before the rising of Windows and GUI.

Here is where you can watch the intro: http://www.artofthetitle.com/title/halt-and-catch-fire/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a snapshot of part of a silicon wafer used to make microprocessors. You take a wafer and split it into a bunch of squares once you've printed a chipset onto it. Then you package each one into one of those black plastic cases with pins (called a package in industry jargon).

[image: From Wikipedia: Silicon Chip Wafer]

Comment: Great stuff, thank you very much! I was that curious!